# syntax error, unexpected '$type' (T_VARIABLE), expecting '(' in

Tags: php

```
  if($_POST) {
  $type = $_POST['roll'];
  if $type == 1 {
    $number = rand(1,100)
    if $number <= 50 {
      echo "Winner!"
    }
    else {
      echo "Loser!"
    }
  }
};
```

Can't figure out what is wrong. I am kinda new to PHP also. Type (or roll) is always 1 (for now)

Comment: here, read this: http://php.net/manual/it/control-structures.if.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to put

```
if ($type == 1) {
```

instead of your actual statement, the condition of the if need that.
And so you'll need it too on the second "if"

Watch what your error is showing, it's exactly what you need.

Comment: That worked but on the second if it says unexpected if (T_IF).

Comment: you forgot the ";"

Comment: Ah, you forgot the ";" of your two echo too